# Cypher match path with different depths

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a question, I have been trying to get information out of a certain situation that has come up in my Neo4j database. Here is the node configuration.

[image: Node Configuration]

I need to get all the nodes that are connected to `a` and for all the incoming connections I need to find there incoming connecting nodes and for the outgoing all of there outgoing nodes.

So i would expect `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `l`, `f` and `e`. Not `g`, `h`, `i`, `j` and `k`.

What ever I try I am not getting the complete set in one query. I get or to much or to little.

```
MATCH (n)-[r]-(m) WHERE n.name="a"
RETURN n,m,r
```

gives just `a`, `b`, `c`, `f` and `l`.

```
MATCH (n)-[r]-(m)-[s]->(x)
WHERE n.name="a"
RETURN n,m,r,s,x
```

, then I lose `b` and `l`.

So I must be doing something wrong. Is there a query that will get me the data I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering this initial data set (The data model shown in the print screen):

```
CREATE (a:Node {name : 'a'})
CREATE (b:Node {name : 'b'})
CREATE (c:Node {name : 'c'})
CREATE (d:Node {name : 'd'})
CREATE (e:Node {name : 'e'})
CREATE (f:Node {name : 'f'})
CREATE (g:Node {name : 'g'})
CREATE (h:Node {name : 'h'})
CREATE (i:Node {name : 'i'})
CREATE (j:Node {name : 'j'})
CREATE (k:Node {name : 'k'})
CREATE (l:Node {name : 'l'})

CREATE (a)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(c)
CREATE (c)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(d)
CREATE (a)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(l)
CREATE (b)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(a)
CREATE (a)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(f)
CREATE (f)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(e)
CREATE (g)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(f)
CREATE (i)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(g)
CREATE (i)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(h)
CREATE (i)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(j)
CREATE (j)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(k)
```

This query should work:

```
// Match de start point 'A'
MATCH (a:Node {name : 'a'})
// Match incoming nodes and optionally (0..1) incoming of incoming nodes
MATCH (a)<-[:CONNECTED_TO]-(b:Node)<-[:CONNECTED_TO*0..1]-(c:Node)
// collect b and c into rows, pass a to the next context
WITH a, collect(b) + collect(c) as rows
// Match outgoing nodes and optionally (0..1) outgoing of outgoing nodes
MATCH (a)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(b:Node)-[:CONNECTED_TO*0..1]->(c:Node)
// collect all into rows
WITH collect(a) + collect(b) + collect(c) + rows as rows
// unwind 
UNWIND rows AS unwinded
// return distinct nodes
RETURN DISTINCT unwinded
ORDER BY unwinded.name
```

The result will be:

```
╒════════════╕
│"unwinded"  │
╞════════════╡
│{"name":"a"}│
├────────────┤
│{"name":"b"}│
├────────────┤
│{"name":"c"}│
├────────────┤
│{"name":"d"}│
├────────────┤
│{"name":"e"}│
├────────────┤
│{"name":"f"}│
├────────────┤
│{"name":"l"}│
└────────────┘
```

**EDIT:**

Refactored query to:

```
MATCH (in2:Node)-[:CONNECTED_TO*0..1]->(in:Node)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(a:Node {name : 'a'})-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(out:Node)-[:CONNECTED_TO*0..1]->(out2:Node)
WITH collect(in2) + collect(in) + collect(a) + collect(out) + collect(out2) as rows
UNWIND rows AS unwinded
RETURN distinct unwinded
ORDER BY unwinded.name
```

The above query produces the same result but using only one `MATCH` for the entire pattern instead of 3 different `MATCH`es.